# ImageMagick: resize image and reduce file size

Tags: image, imagemagick

Using [ImageMagick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick), I'm trying to resize a JPEG's dimensions and reduce the file size.

The issue is that I don't want to worsen the image quality.

I've tried the following commands:

```
convert -resize 170x80 -resample 100x100 image1.jpg image2.jpg
```

=> A resized picture but with bad quality.

```
convert -resize 170x80 -quality JPEG image1.jpg image2.jpg
```

=> A resized image and with good quality, but the same file size.

```
convert -density 600 -resize 170x80 image1.jpg image2.jpg
```

=> A resized image but very bad quality.

I don't know what option I should use.

Comment: Image compression using the JPEG format is going to result in some loss of quality regardless of how you go about it.  You may want to try a different format if absolutely lossless compression is what you need, but without a sample image, I don't know what option to recommend for your use case.  The compression article on Wikipedia lists some lossless options that you might consider:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_compression1

Comment: What is your input image size? Perhaps you can post your input image and tell us what file size you want for the output. Have you seen the `-define jpeg:extent={size}` for writing output JPG to a given file size? See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#jpg_write. NOTE: density will not change the file size of a raster image. It only affects the printed size of the output. NOTE: your syntax is wrong, though for ImageMagick 6 it may not matter. Proper syntax reads the input first, then settings, then commands, then the output.

Comment: If you are shrinking a very large file (WxH) to 170x80, then you may very well lose quality do to too large a jump in dimension for the resize filters. You may want to go down in a series of steps of -scale 50% until you get close and then -resize 170x80. Or alternately, try adding different -filter options. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/ and https://imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/nicolas/

Comment: If you post an example input, we can offer better suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've managed to solve this issue using `convert` and `mogrify` :

```
convert -flatten -colorspace RGB myImage.jpg myImage.jpg 
&& 
mogrify -quality JPEG -geometry 170x80 myImage.jpg
```

Answer (score 16):

`quality` parameter has a numeric value. From [-quality doc](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality) :

> For the JPEG and MPEG image formats, quality is 1 (lowest image quality and highest compression) to 100 (best quality but least effective compression). The default is to use the estimated quality of your input image if it can be determined, otherwise 92.

You may use quality lower than the default 92 to reduce the size, e.g. 72 as:

```
convert -resize 170x80 -quality 72 image1.jpg image2.jpg
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried that, the file size has reduced, but the image quality is not good

Comment: Then try `75` instead, then `80`, then `85` etc. Untill the need size-quality ratio